# Angular Routing scroll to element

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am trying to make it so that when I click on one of the solutions links below (eg solutions/click) the page scrolls to that element on the page.

```
  <li><a routerLink="/solutions" routerLinkActive="active"  class="main-links separate highlight">{{'NAVIGATION_SOLUTIONS'|translate}}</a>
                    <ul class="nav-dropdown set-width items">
                        <li><a routerLink="/solutions/click">{{'NAVIGATION_CLICK_COLLECT'|translate}}</a></li>
                        <li><a routerLink="/solutions/returns">{{'NAVIGATION_STORE_RETURNS'|translate}}</a></li>
                        <li><a routerLink="/solutions/aisle">{{'NAVIGATION_ENDLESS_AISLE'|translate}}</a></li>
                        <li><a routerLink="/solutions/store">{{'NAVIGATION_STORE_FULFILMENT'|translate}}</a></li>
                        <li><a routerLink="/solutions/customer">{{'NAVIGATION_CUSTOMER_CARE'|translate}}</a></li>
                        <li><a routerLink="/solutions/partner">{{'NAVIGATION_PARTNER_FULFILMENT'|translate}}</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Here are my routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'homepage', component: HomepageComponent},
  { path: 'homepage/:id', component: HomepageComponent},
  { path: 'solutions', component: SolutionsComponent},
  { path: 'solutions/:id', component: SolutionsComponent},
  { path: 'work', component: WorkComponent }
];
```

And this is the part I am stuck on. I have gotten it to recognise the id (eg click, returns, etc). but i can't figure out how to go about having the page scroll to the element. Does anyone know what I should do here? (Sorry if this is a dumb questions, I have only been using Angular for the last week and feeling very confused)

```
 ngOnInit() {    
    this.route.params
    .map(params => params['id'])
    .subscribe((id) => {
      this.scrollTo(id)
      console.log(id);
    });
  }

  scrollTo(id: string) {


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a third-party module to achieve your desired result. You can checkout [ngx-page-scroll](https://github.com/Nolanus/ngx-page-scroll).

Once you have retrieved the id you wish to scroll to, you can use the `PageScrollService` from the module to start a scroll animation to your desired anchor. You must give `ids` to each of the sub-components in your `SolutionsComponent`. Note that these should match the id you click in your link. Then you can utilize the `PageScrollService's` start method to start the scroll. You can checkout the full detailed example (and imports) at this link: https://github.com/Nolanus/ngx-page-scroll#service

Here's a sample code to give you an idea of what you need to do

```
//solutions.component.ts
constructor(
    private pageScrollService: PageScrollService, @Inject(DOCUMENT) 
    private document: any) {}

ngOnInit() {    
    this.route.params
    .map(params => params['id'])
    .subscribe((id) => {
      this.scrollTo(id)
      console.log(id);
    });
  }

scrollTo(id: string) {
     let pageScrollInstance: PageScrollInstance = PageScrollInstance.simpleInstance(this.document, '#' + id);
     this.pageScrollService.start(pageScrollInstance);
  }


//solutions.component.html
 <div id="aisle">
    ...
 </div>
 <div id="returns">
    ...
 </div>
 ...
```